# Find the number of similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given that
> $S=\{A:C_A(x)=(x-5)^5(x-2)^4(x-1)^2\}$
> Where $A$ is $11\times 11$ matrix
> Then find the minimum number of matrices which guarantees that at least two are similar

My answer is the number of such matrices is $5\cdot 4\cdot 2=40$

Please help me to answer this question
Thank you

Comment: So essentially you were asked to find the number of similarity classes of matrices that have that characteristic polynomial, and add $1$.

Comment: What Jordan form can such a matrix have?